# MobileFirst Platform Operational Analytics in Native iOS Swift applications

Tags: swift, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode7, mobilefirst-analytics

I'm developing a native iOS MobileFirst application in XCode 7 (Swift) and MobileFirst 7.0.

I want to use MobileFirst Operational Analytics and I'm following this guidelines:

[https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/moving-production/operational-analytics/][1]

I have some questions:

- The sessions should be automatically recorded but it is not being the case of the application. I just see the data for 1 device as connected when more devices have connected the last 24 hours. **How can I enable this feature?** **or it should be automatic with the equivalent of WL.Connect() in native iOS?**
- The adapter calls should be  automatic too but can be just be visualized under the tab: Network->Adapters Overview-> Adapter Request & Network->Adapters Overview-> Adapter Request but I can't see the pie charts generated: Calls Per Application Procedure Calls, Calls Per Server. They only show as http requests. **How can this charts be generated too?**
- I will like to do custom charts and make use of the WL.Analytics.log(), WL.Analytics.send(), etc. **How are this calls translated to swift? I only see this fro Hybrid apps, is there any documentation about this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering 1)

I realized that I wasn't connecting successfully to the MobileFirst server. Once I successfully connect the sessions were recorded automatically by the the MobileFirst Operatinal Analytics tool. The code is:

```
let connectListener = MyConnectListener()
WLClient.sharedInstance().wlConnectWithDelegate(connectListener)
```

Answering 2)

When invoking the adapters in this way, the Mobilefirst Operational Analytics does not collect the information for the pie charts, it registers this calls as http calls:

```
let request = WLResourceRequest(URL: NSURL!, method: String!)
```

You have to invoke the adapters like this so that the pie charts are automatically generated:

```
let myInvocationData = WLProcedureInvocationData(adapterName: String!, procedureName: String!)
```

Answering 3)

Using the following code in swift analytics were successfully send to the server.

```
let doAnaylitics = WLAnalytics.sharedInstance()
doAnaylitics.enable()
doAnaylitics.log("type", withMetadata:["location":location])
doAnaylitics.send()
doAnaylitics.disable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering 3)

> I will like to do custom charts and make use of the WL.Analytics.log(), WL.Analytics.send(), etc. How are this calls translated to swift? I only see this fro Hybrid apps, is there any documentation about this?

There is no API available for Swift, but you can continue to use Objective-C code in Swift applications: [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Also see the following section to configure your Swift application: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/#configSwiftApp